# Decimal to Binary program not working on my local machine but works perfectly on online compiler

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, bitwise-and

I was writing a C++ program to convert decimal to binary, but my local system is giving different and wrong output, but when i run same program on programiz c++ online compiler it gives desired output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    // system("CLS");
    cout<<"DECIMAL TO BINARY"<<endl;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int ans=0;
    int i=0;
    while(n){
        // extracting last bit
        // if last bit is 0 then 0&1->0
        // if last bit is 1 then 1&1->1
        int last_bit=(n&1);
        ans=(last_bit*pow(10, i))+ans;
        i++;
        // removing last bit
        n>>=1;
    }
    cout<<ans;
}
```

is it the logic of above code wrong or compiler dependent?

[The output on my local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1govW.png)
not getting binary output
[The Output on programiz c++ online compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfBGw.png)
getting binary output

Comment: `pow(10, i)` probably does not do what you want it to do.

Comment: Don't use `pow`; that's for floating-point math. Use an integer multiplier, and multiply it by 10 each time through the loop: `unsigned mult = 1; ... ans += bit * mult; mult *= 10;`.

Comment: Note, however, that this does **not** produce a binary representation of the value. It produces a **decimal** number that, when printed out, has 1s and 0s that represent the original value as binary. Binary and decimal are ways of representing values; they are **text**, not numbers.

Comment: Also add `if (n < 0) throw "number too small"; if (n > 511) throw "number too big";`.

Comment: TLDR it is wrong : This must be about the most asked question on stackoverflow "why does my decimal to binary conversion not work". Never mix floating point functions with integer math.  Also note that each decimal number is already stored as binary number in memory (so you need powers of 2 not 10). You only need to pickup the bits using bitwise operators and shifting.

Comment: Watch this before you continue using floating point numbers : [Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0)

Comment: Also know C++ has build in functionality for what you want see [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: Are you sure you are running the last build of your code? maybe the script you are using to build is "failing" somehow without notice

Comment: I highly recommend storing the binary representation in a string.  An `int` will only reliably hold 16 bits (the `int` is by range).  The `std::string` can hold a lot more bits.

Comment: Why this way? Why beginners, so often when trying convert int to string with binary representation, by trying create value which printed as decimal will look like desired output. This is so silly and bug prone. Somewhere in dark corners of internet there must be somewhere harmful course which teaches this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Post them as text instead.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Information unnecessarily posted as image is considered missing debugging details.